# Select a Value from a table which contains Comma separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have these two tables:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

The two tables are joined on `ID`.

I will have 2 parameters, `Person` and `Resource`, and I have to select the corresponding `Order`. `Resource` is always unique and might be stored as CSV.

Example: I will have `Person 3` and `Resource 7` as inputs and I should get `Order 5` as output.

This has to be done in SQL Server and I cannot use `STRING_SPLIT` (compatibility issues).

Comment: The better solution would be to not store comma separated values.

Comment: @juergend Customer is storing that way, nothing I can do on that front.

Comment: If tables join by ID, on your example output is nothing.

Comment: @FranCerezo Person 3 and Res 4 have ID4, they will join on ID4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX() function`
The `PATINDEX() function` returns the position of a pattern in a string.

If the pattern is not found, this function returns 0.

```
SELECT *, X.Order
FROM Table1 X
JOIN Table2 Y
    ON X.ID = Y.ID
WHERE
    X. Person = 'Person3' AND
    PATINDEX ('%,Res7,%',CONCAT(',',Y.Resource,',') )>0
```

Comment: Note: Your `WHERE` clause, as written, would also have a false match for `Res70`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using a trick to compare the CSV string of resources:

```
SELECT t1.[Order]
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.Person = 'Person3' AND
    ',' + t2.Resource + ',' LIKE '%,Res7,%';
```

But, as mentioned in the comments, it would be best to move away from storing CSV in your tables.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there anyway not to use Like.
This is a perfectly acceptable solution, just wondering if the cost to run LIKE command can be cut down

Comment: Not really...other than maybe `STRING_SPLIT` (which you said is not an option for you).  Hence, you can see why you should avoid CSV.